# twitter4j - setSince and setUntil don't work

Tags: twitter4j

I'm having problem to filter tweets by specifics dates, using setUntil come no tweets, using setSince come recently tweets.. The code is following and after that the output result..

```
public void readTweetFromKeyword(String keywordString) throws TwitterException
{
    twitter4j.Query query =new twitter4j.Query("#clt20");
    QueryResult result;

    query.setSince("2014-12-12");

    int cont = 0;

    result = twitter.search(query);
    for (Status status : result.getTweets() )
    {
        System.out.print("original "+status.getId());
        System.out.println("\t\tdata "+status.getCreatedAt());

        if(!status.getText().substring(0, 2).equals("RT")){
            System.out.println(status.getText());
            cont++;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(result.getTweets().size());
    System.out.println("cont = "+cont);
    return;     
}
```

CONSOLE:

> original 619433499116896256       data Fri Jul 10 06:10:29 GMT-03:00 2015
>   If the @BCCI is looking for an alternative to #Clt20, then how about a
>   league of teams consisting of only Indian players ?
>
> original 619408117495939072       data Fri Jul 10 04:29:37 GMT-03:00 2015
>    #TesT, #ODI, #T20I, #IPL, #CLT20 Live record, score, history shedule ke lia, Follow @PTV_SpOrtsOne snt to 40404.
>
> original 619330143258050560       data Thu Jul 09 23:19:47 GMT-03:00 2015
>   Need 66 From 6 Balls. Kinda Impossible #clt20
>
> original 619301555532120065       data Thu Jul 09 21:26:11 GMT-03:00 2015
>   Kamran Akmals feet are stuck #soshit #CLT20
>
> original 619095093962608640       data Thu Jul 09 07:45:47 GMT-03:00 2015
>
> original 619095079983017984       data Thu Jul 09 07:45:43 GMT-03:00 2015
>
> original 619095051524665344       data Thu Jul 09 07:45:37 GMT-03:00 2015
>
> original 619095028304973825       data Thu Jul 09 07:45:31 GMT-03:00 2015
>
> original 619094989943902209       data Thu Jul 09 07:45:22 GMT-03:00 2015
>
> original 619094910516400129       data Thu Jul 09 07:45:03 GMT-03:00 2015
>
> original 619094893441363969       data Thu Jul 09 07:44:59 GMT-03:00 2015
>
> original 619035151578722304       data Thu Jul 09 03:47:35 GMT-03:00 2015
>   @abhisek_taneja Games r played in Himachal Pradesh every year if u go
>   through the schedule of #IPL & #CLT20 properly
>
> original 618914815730290688       data Wed Jul 08 19:49:25 GMT-03:00 2015
>
> original 618908444939186177       data Wed Jul 08 19:24:06 GMT-03:00 2015
>
> original 618862474687705088       data Wed Jul 08 16:21:26 GMT-03:00 2015
>   We as #T20 follower , @clt20 should be oganized #CLT20
>
> 15 cont = 6

Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 0):

If you set an until date kepp in mind this from [the documentation](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/search/tweets)

> Returns tweets generated before the given date. Date should be
>   formatted as YYYY-MM-DD. Keep in mind that the search index may not go
>   back as far as the date you specify here.

And this too

> Before getting involved, it’s important to know that the Search API is
>   focused on relevance and not completeness. This means that some Tweets
>   and users may be missing from search results. If you want to match for
>   completeness you should consider using a Streaming API instead.

So, if you set an until date too old you could get zero tweets, in the other hand if you set a since date too old you could get only tweets from the few past days as you get in the console.

Comment: The for answer, but like in the code I had set for 1 year ago and didn't work.. It returns like I hadn't set anything